# how to find and replace multiple words?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, css

i want to find and replace multiple words ? i find this code this is working fine but only one text work, how can i add multiple words..

> 

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(onMutation);
observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true, // report added/removed nodes
    subtree: true,   // observe any descendant elements
});

function onMutation(mutations, observer) {
    for (var i = 0, len = mutations.length; i < len; i++) {
        var added = mutations[i].addedNodes;
        for (var j = 0, node; (node = added[j]); j++) {
            replaceText(node);  
        }
    }
}

function replaceText(el) {
    let target_string = "winter";
    let replacement_string = "summer";

    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
    for (let node; (node = walker.nextNode());) {
        const text = node.nodeValue;
        const newText = text.replace(target_string, replacement_string);
        if (text !== newText) {
            node.nodeValue = newText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about the python?

Comment: thanks for reply. pls help me this code working fine only one text, i want to add multi text, how can i use code with multi code, i dont know much about python or javascrip :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the same code with a dict where the key, values of your dict represent the target and replacement string as such.

```
function replaceMultipleWords(str, wordsObj) {
  let re = new RegExp(Object.keys(wordsObj).join("|"), "gi");

  return str.replace(re, function (matched) {
    return wordsObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
  });
}

let wordsObj = {
  winter: "summer",
  spring: "fall",
  happy: "sad",
};

let test_string = "winter is coming, but happy spring is here.";

console.log(replaceMultipleWords(test_string, wordsObj));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply :-) but not work, use user javascript and css extension on google chrome to use this code. only my code work and replace one text only, but i want to replace multipe text inject, and i use obs to screen on my live project.

Comment: Please anyone help me to fix this code

Comment: @XenLeaks The update should work for you.

Comment: thanks for reply, but not work

Comment: @XenLeaks Can you update your question and point out what is the exact problem you are facing ?